# Issue in open Keyboard in ionic application

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello friends i m new in ionic developer so in my application i integrate keyboard plugin for open from footer and focus field for enter value . Below    i use link for plugin

https://gist.github.com/Manduro/bc121fd39f21558df2a952b39e907754

And in my html page i call it as below

```
<ion-content #content>
<ion-item no-padding>
<ion-label floating>Name (*) </ion-label>
<ion-input #txtGroupName type="text" [(ngModel)]="client.name"></ion-input>
```

```
<ion-footer no-padding no-margin class="custom-footer"  [keyboardAttach]="content">
      <button ion-button full no-padding no-margin (click)="onClickAddClientContact()">CREATE</button>
  </ion-footer>
```

When i run above code i get error like **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Keyboard!**

any idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am using in my app, without footer. without issue.

```
<form class="loginForm">
                <div class="list">
                  <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" class="input1" placeholder="Username" id='username'>
                  </label>
                  <label class="item item-input">
                      <input type="password"  class="input2" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
                  </label>
                </div>
    <button class="button" id="btn-submit" ng-click="submit()">Sign In</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: raj peer : issue is when i type in my screen at that time keyboard is overlap on that field so i can not see what i type on it so i need to that up when i typing from keyboard

Comment: use simple input element <input> instead of <ion-input> and see

Comment: raj peer  : i want my footer button up from keyboard when i start typing